# jQuery UI datepicker - show the week numbers on the right side of the calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker for one of my projects. Per design the datepicker should show the numbers of weeks as well, which functionality the jQuery UI datepicker already has. However, in that plugin the week numbers are shown on the left side of the calendar while per design I need to show them on the right side. Is there an easier way to do that rather than changing the JavaScript source of the plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is an easier way. using CSS and adding `position:absolute` and utilizing `top: Npx & right: Npx`

Comment: Maybe it's enough to add a style that switches the container sides by using floats.

Comment: Changing the source is actually faster in that case. I just can't find the non-compressed version of jQuery UI. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never change the source directly. It may be faster now, but will cause you LOTS of problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks. In that case how could I change it indirectly? How can I override that setting? That's actually an HTML markup there.